# Code's not compiling because of nested anonymous blocks?

Tags: c++

(Taken from Accelerated C++)

Why does the following code not work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    {
        const std::string s = "a string";
        std::cout << s << std::endl;

        {
            const std::string s = "another string";
            std::cout << s << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Am I not allowed to nest anonymous blocks in C++? When trying to compile the source, gcc gives me the following error (which I can't make any sense of):

> ```
> hello: In function `_start':
> (.text+0x0): multiple definition of
> `_start'
> /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crt1.o:(.text+0x0):
> first defined here
> hello:(.rodata+0x0): multiple
> definition of `_fp_hw'
> /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crt1.o:(.rodata+0x0):
> first defined here hello: In function
> `_fini': (.fini+0x0): multiple
> definition of `_fini'
> /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crti.o:(.fini+0x0):
> first defined here
> hello:(.rodata+0x4): multiple
> definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
> /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0):
> first defined here hello: In function
> `__data_start': (.data+0x0): multiple
> definition of `__data_start'
> /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crt1.o:(.data+0x0):
> first defined here hello: In function
> `__data_start': (.data+0x4): multiple
> definition of `__dso_handle'
> /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0):
> first defined here hello: In function
> `_init': (.init+0x0): multiple
> definition of `_init'
> /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crti.o:(.init+0x0):
> first defined here /tmp/cchh83A6.o: In
> function `main':
> hello.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple
> definition of `main'
> hello:(.text+0xb4): first defined here
> /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/crtend.o:(.dtors+0x0):
> multiple definition of `__DTOR_END__'
> hello:(.dtors+0x4): first defined here
> /usr/bin/ld: warning: Cannot create
> .eh_frame_hdr section, --eh-frame-hdr
> ignored. /usr/bin/ld: error in
> hello(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr
> table will be created. collect2: ld
> returned 1 exit status
> ```

Comment: What command(s) are you using to compile and link this? Also, if you remove the "anonymous block", do you still have the error?

Comment: The error seems to be in your build environment, not in your code. Please post some info about your IDE and building setup (a makefile?) and the building command generated (you might see it in a console just before the output you've posted).

Comment: What would a named (non-anonymous) block look like? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be linking against 2, or more, object files (or .a files) that define the same things.  If you link against one or the other your linker problem will go away.

Comment: D'oh. You're right, this was the problem. Instead of `g++ -o hello hello.cpp` it wrote `g++ hello hello.cpp`.

Answer (score 6):

That code works fine. See here [Your code compiled](http://codepad.org/PJUed44Y) (You have a problem with your environment)